# How to pass data from controller view to angular scope?

Tags: angularjs

I have a C# MVC web application and I have started exploring the use of AngularJS to make my views cleaner.

I would like to pass data retrieved from my model(SQL database) into Angular scopes. All the AngularJS examples I have seen so far passes data into the scope in a JSON format:

```
Example:
$scope.contacts = [
{type:'phone', value:'408 555 1212'},
{type:'email', value:'john.smith@example.org'} ];
```

I would like to know if it’s possible to pass data from a controller view directly into a Angular scope without using the JSON format.

Example say my controller returns the following view.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  Var mymodel = mydatarepository.getdate();
  Return View(mymodel);
}
```

How can I pass the view returned in the above into a Angular scope without using json?

Comment: angularjs is meant for SPA and dynamic application only first page should be served using View option for rest of app either return json or partialhtml result

Comment: Your C# application must somehow encode the data for it to be sent to the client, the typical scenario is to encode to JSON (more popular recently mostly due to the ubiquity and ease of parsing/processing/relatively small overhead), another option is XML.  Still another option is AMF (ActionScript Message Format) or some other binary serialization of objects that can be encoded and decoded at both ends.

Comment: You could return the JSON data from another action and call it from an AngularJS controller.

Comment: Ok. Thanks guys. I have no problem using json but was just wondering If there is an alternative.